# При использовании jquery address не срабатывает ajax load

Tags: jquery

Подскажите. Воспользовался плагином `jquery address`, url меняется но `ajax load` не происходит. Подскажите, какая ошибка в коде? Заранее спасибо!!

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var init = true, 
            state = window.history.pushState !== undefined;

        // Handles response
        var handler = function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
            var data = $.parseJSON(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            $.address.title(data.title);
            $('.container').html(data.content);
        };

        $.address.state('/myprogect/').init(function(event) {

            // Initializes the plugin
            $('a').address();

        }).change(function(event) {

            var value = $.address.state().replace(/^\/$/, '') + event.value;

            // Selects the proper navigation link
            // Selects the proper navigation link
            $('a').each(function() {
                if ($(this).attr('href') == value) {
                    $(this).addClass('selected').focus();
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('selected');
                }
            });
            if (state && init) {

                init = false;

            } else {

                // Loads and populates the page data
                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    complete: handler,
                    url: value
                });
            }

        });

        if (!state) {

            // Hides the page during initialization
            document.write('<style type="text/css"> body { display: none; } </style>');
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: тебе нужно что бы он просто подгружал файл без перезагрузки меняя url, правильно?

Comment: Да,вы правильно мыслите!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я делал так

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.address.change(function(event) {  
        // do something depending on the event.value property, e.g.
        if (event.value == '/') {
                event.value = '/home';
            }
            $('.content').load(event.value + '.php');
            $('a[href="'+event.value+'"]').addClass('selected').focus();
    });

    $('a').address(function() {
        $('a').removeClass('selected').focus();
        $(this).addClass('selected').focus();
        $('title').text($(this).attr('title'));
        return $(this).attr('href').replace(/^#/, '');
    });
</script>
```

И вот html

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a class="" href="home" title="Главная страница">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="guestbook" title="Гостевая книга">Гостевая</a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="contact" title="Контакты">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="content">

</div>
```

Правда ссылка не выделяется пока не нашел решение(если по прямой заходят)
При нажатии на ссылку подгружает файл

Comment: Вообще плохо что про него нет статей подробных на русском...(((

Comment: А почему у вас в коде javascript,нечего не сказано про изменение истории ?Только загрузка ?

Comment: а она обязательна разве? тут подправил еще маленько...теперь при прямом заходе ссылка тоже выделится. 
я не спец конечно, но все работает...

Comment: Ну да при нажатии на Контакты подгружается contact,а url меняется ?Где код который меняет url после загрузки ?

Comment: все меняется на ура...давай я тебе скину все файлы, посмотришь

Comment: Ок,скиньте пожалуйста!